# TCP connection forcibly closed by ShipModul's Miniplex-3Wi

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, nmea

We have been developing a .NET Framework 4.6.1 app with C# that has as one of its tasks to send NMEA 0183 sentences to a multiplexer via local area network connection (Wi-Fi or Ethernet). The app can be configured to connect using TCP or UDP. The communication between the app and the multiplexer works over UDP for hours without any problems, but TCP connection has this problem that a ShipModul's multiplexer that I have been using in my own testing scenarios forcibly closes the connection after about 10 or 15 minutes. Also, other users of the app have confirmed that other multiplexers might not work at all when the app is configured to use TCP, but that UDP connection still works without a problem. The communication is one-way from the .NET Framework app to multiplexer.

What might be the reason for the premature closing of the TCP connection? Is there some requirement and mechanism to actively keep the connection alive, and not just that it is assumed to be alive when IP packets arrive from the PC? And if the connection needs to be actively maintained, then how you do it with .NET `TcpClient` object?

Simplyt put, the code is something like (executed only when using TCP):

```
// connection initilization
tcpClient = new TcpClient(new IPEndPoint(unicastAddress.Address, port));
tcpClient.Connect(ipAddress, port);
networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
// ..prepare the NMEA sentence data..
networkStream.Write(asciiEncodedNmeaData, 0, asciiEncodedNmeaData.Length);
```

The corresponding UDP protocol version of the code (executed only when using UDP):

```
// connection initialization
udpClient = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(unicastAddress.Address, port));
udpClient.Connect(ipAddress, port);
// ..prepare the NMEA sentence data..
udpClient.Send(asciiEncodedNmeaData, asciiEncodedNmeaData.Length);
```

Also, when the app is closed/paused, the `Close()` method is called on either of the above client object depending on which protocol is used (and everything restarts as above when the app is unpaused):

```
tcpClient.Close();
networkStream.Close();
```

or:

```
udpClient.Close();
```

Then, after about 15 minutes there appears this exception:
System.IO.IOException: 'Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.'

Comment: There isn't anything in tcp that would cause this. Are you correctly formatting the tcp send? Nmea has variable length sentences and you're not checking that all bytes were sent. How does the multiplexor know that it has received a complete sentence? Is it newline char?

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard situation. TCP connection is stateful, i.e. consumes finite resources like memory. That's why network equipment usually discards inactive connections. In your case connection is considered idle "after about 10 or 15 minutes".

To avoid this, you can send "keep alive packets". Just write any data (the less the better) to `networkStream` by timer, e.g. every 5 minutes.